# I want to make an automatic legend in seaborn, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

**I want to make an automatic legend in seaborn, but it doesn't work. How can I generate the legend automatically?**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
sns.pointplot(data=tmp_hs_df, x="Geographic Area", y="percent", color="lime", alpha=0.8, label="High School Not Graduated Rate")
sns.pointplot(data=tmp_poverty_df, x="Geographic Area", y="percent", color="red", alpha=0.8, label="Poverty Rate")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("States")
plt.ylabel("Percent")
plt.title("High School Not Graduate Rate AND Poverty Rate")
plt.grid()
```

tmp_hs_df and tmp_poverty_df

[image: tmp_hs_df and tmp_poverty_df]

chart

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 11)
y1 = 20 - x
y2 = 15 - 0.8*x
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,
                   'y1': y1,
                   'y2': y2})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 10))
sns.pointplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y1', color = 'lime', alpha = 0.8)
sns.pointplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y2', color = 'red', alpha = 0.8)
ax.legend(handles = ax.lines[::len(df) + 1], labels = ['High School Not Graduated Rate', 'Poverty Rate'])
ax.set_xlabel('States')
ax.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax.set_title('High School Not Graduate Rate AND Poverty Rate')
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

which makes this plot:

[image]

You can manage the legend with the line:

```
ax.legend(handles = ax.lines[::len(df) + 1], labels = ['High School Not Graduated Rate', 'Poverty Rate'])
```

I used auto-generated data in order to make a plot, replace them with your data.